# how to get text from Webpage to our local html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to read text from webpage to our html page using jquery or javascript.

What i am trying to do is:
I have one SHOUTcast page, `http://79.120.77.11:9007/`

Where every 5-6 mins current songs keep changing, I need to read currect song name and display in html textbox.

How can I do it?

Comment: Quick googling gave me this: https://github.com/Wavestreaming/jquery-shoutcast

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it if both the pages are on different hosts and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not set up

Check http://enable-cors.org/

In case they are on same server then use this

```
$('#my_div').load('http://79.120.77.11:9007/ #element_with_song_name');
```